# Problemas de conexión al enviar datos a MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy intentando por medio de un registro en php mandar datos a una tabla en mysql pero me dice que tengo un error en la linea 14 de la variable "$query".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$nombre = $_POST['name'];
$puesto = $_POST['puesto'];
$depa = $_POST['departamento'];
$anti = $_POST['antiguedad'];
$reco = $_POST['reconocimientos'];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO colaboradores(Id, Nombre, Puesto, Departamento, Antiguedad, Reconocimientos) VALUES ('$id','$nombre','$puesto','$depa','$anti','$reco')";


$query = mysqli_query($con, $insertar);

if ($query) {
  echo '<script> alert("OK"); 
  
  location.href="index.php";
  
  </script>';
}
```

Comment: El problema es que alguno de los valores que le pasas te esta generando algun error, revisa que la coneción y la consulta esten bien hechas, con un `var_dump` lo puedes ver

Comment: `undefined variable $con`, significa que la variable de conexión no se llama $con por lo que va a generar el otro error: `Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, null given`. Revisa el nombre de la conexión en `config.php` y de paso verifica si los credenciales y configuración están correctos.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, ya revise la conexión y ya pude resolverlo.

Comment: Estaría bien que agregaras cual fue el error, en forma de respuesta

Comment: No te está diciendo en la variable $query, te está diciendo en esa línea pero el error es que la variable $con no está definida. Es básico que sepas lidiar con este tipo de errores y puedas depurarlos tú mismo, fórmate un poco más ;)

Answer (score 1):

El error que te muestra es que no tienes la variable $con, la cual debería venir de conexion.php pero al parecer no llega por eso te marca undefined
Para crear la conexión lo puedes hacer como te dejo abajo, solo debes cambiar el username, password y nombre de la base de datos. También coloque un echo para que veas si conecta a la BD

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "Contrasena";
    $dbname = "Nombre Base de Datos";

    // Creas la Conexion
    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Aqui ves si te da un error
    if ($con->connect_error) {
       die("Error en la Conexion: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }else{
        echo "Conectado";
     }


$id = $_POST['id'];
$nombre = $_POST['name'];
$puesto = $_POST['puesto'];
$depa = $_POST['departamento'];
$anti = $_POST['antiguedad'];
$reco = $_POST['reconocimientos'];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO colaboradores(Id, Nombre, Puesto, Departamento, Antiguedad, Reconocimientos) VALUES ('$id','$nombre','$puesto','$depa','$anti','$reco')";


$query = mysqli_query($con, $insertar);

if ($query) {
  echo '<script> alert("OK"); 
  
  location.href="index.php";
  
  </script>';
}
```